# function mapCharAndSum(N,K,str)

Tags: javascript, string, object, for-in-loop

Map Characters & Sum Ended
Description

You are given a number stored in a variable with the nameN

You are also, given a string, whose length is stored in a variable with the nameK, and the string is stored in a variable with the namestr

You have to map all lower case English characters, starting from the value stored inN.

For example, if the value stored inN = 30, then the mapping of the characters will be as follows

a-30
b-31
c-32
d-33
e-34
f-35
g-36
h-37
i-38
j-39
k-40
l-41
m-42
n-43
o-44
p-45
q-46
r-47
s-48
t-49
u-50
v-51
w-52
x-53
y-54
z-55
Finally, you have to print the sum of all the characters, present in the stringstr, according to the values mapped above

For example, if the value stored instr = "abc", then the required output will be

30 + 31 + 32 = 93, which is the required output

Input
The first line of the input contains the value stored inN

The second line of the input contains the value stored inK

The last line of the input contains the value stored in thestr

Output
Print the sum of characters, according to the values mapped, as shown in the problem statement

Sample Input 1

30
3
abc
Sample Output 1

93
Hint

In the sample test case, the value stored inN = 30, then the mapping of the characters will be as follows

a-30
b-31
c-32
d-33
e-34
f-35
g-36
h-37
i-38
j-39
k-40
l-41
m-42
n-43
o-44
p-45
q-46
r-47
s-48
t-49
u-50
v-51
w-52
x-53
y-54
z-55
Finally, you have to print the sum of all the characters, present in the stringstr, according to the values mapped above

For example, if the value stored instr = "abc", then the required output will be

30 + 31 + 32 = 93, which is the required output

[code in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CPBA.png)

Comment: where is the code? please add it.

Comment: i add it in image

Comment: come on. please add it in text from. how should we edit an image?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Homework questions (or, in your case, online coding questions) can't simply be copy pasted into SO. In fact, questions like these will be quickly closed and possibly deleted. Show what you have tried ([in image format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14469685), please) and explain exactly what you can't figure out how to do. See [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/14469685) for tips on how to write a homework question (or any other similar type).

Comment: About my original comment - I meant NOT in image format. The link describes many (but even that isn't all of them) reasons why you shouldn't post images of code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function mapCharAndSum(n, str) {
  let alphabet = [ ...Array(26).keys() ]
  let alphabetWithValues = alphabet.map(num => [ String.fromCharCode(97 + num), n + num ])
  let values = Array.from(str).map(char => alphabetWithValues.find(item => item[0] === char)[1])
  return values.join(' + ') + ' = ' + values.reduce((sum, value) => sum + value)
}

console.log(mapCharAndSum(30, 'abc'))             
// Output: 30 + 31 + 32 = 93

console.log(mapCharAndSum(0, 'stackoverflow'))     
// Output: 18 + 19 + 0 + 2 + 10 + 14 + 21 + 4 + 17 + 5 + 11 + 14 + 22 = 157

console.log(mapCharAndSum(15, 'stack overflow'))   
// Crashes, because ' ' is not part of the alphabet and there is no error handling
```